# Xamarin: detect page pushed on NavigationRenderer

Tags: xamarin, navigation, custom-controls

I order to apply some  navigationBar properties (like as the background image) for different page, I think to have a condition on my custom NavigationRenderer.

My idea is to have some condition like (in my  working code)

```
   public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationRenderer
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        if (pagePushed is 1)
        {
            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
            NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
        }

        else (ahother page){
            var img = UIImage.FromBundle("MyImage");
            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(img, UIBarMetrics.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

that allows me to have at least a condition to apply a different navigation properties. Another way is to have 2 Navigationrenderer class but I think is not possible.

Any idea to how do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `NavigationRenderer` [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/NavigationRenderer.cs), you will notice there are quite a few methods and callbacks you can take advantage of.

I would suggest you can do something like this:

1) Code for your custom NavigationRenderer (iOS project, you will have to do something similar on Android):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyProject.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(NavRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS
{
    public class NavRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override async Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page page, bool animated)
        {
            var result = await base.OnPushAsync(page, animated);

            if(result)
            {
                if (page is IMyPageType1)
                {
                    NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
                    NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
                }

                else if(page is IMyPageType2)
                {
                    var img = UIImage.FromBundle("MyImage");
                    NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(img, UIBarMetrics.Default);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Based on the code above, you need to add two interfaces. These should be located in the same project / dll where your Pages are located (all your Xamarin.Forms UI):

```
    public interface IMyPageType1
    {
    }

    public interface IMyPageType2
    {
    }
```

3) Now everything that's remaining is implement the interfaces on the pages where you need it. For example:

```
    public partial class MyPage1 : ContentPage, IMyPageType1
    {
        //...
    }
```

From here, possibilities are endless! You can add for example a method to `IMyPageType1` that would return a color, and then inside your renderer, once you know the page being pushed is implementing `IMyPageType1`, you can call the method and get the color to use.

Comment: Nice. Tx!  Could you know I can override OnPopViewAsync? I try but it be called after the base pop

Comment: Not sure what the requirement is, but I would start by overriding the method and placing the call to base at the end of it